# Order by query in Mongoid failing to order

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Trying to create a nice ordered list, I have the method which I know work that are which are in the Participant class

```
def countries_ive_drunk
    had_drinks.map {|drink| drink.beer.country }
  end

  def countries_ive_drunk_count
    countries_ive_drunk.count
  end
```

Knowning that these above work. I have created a new class which would like to get a list of participants and order it by the countries_ive_drunk_count

```
class Drinkers
  include Mongoid::Document

  def self.top_ten_drinkers
    Participant.order_by([[:countries_ive_drunk_count, :asc]]).limit(10)
  end
end
```

but when this is passed down to my haml file:

```
get '/' do
  @topdrinkers = Drinkers.top_ten_drinkers

  haml :index
end
```

Then it isn't ordered correctly. and the below code results in names with the count next to them. The counts are not asc or desc, and just in a random order (probably the order the user were entered into mongodb

```
  %ul        
    - @topdrinkers.all.each do |participant|
      %li
        = "#{participant.countries_ive_drunk_count} - #{participant.name}"
```

Am I missing anything obvious (be nice its my first time using ruby, mongodb, mongoid, haml... throwing myself in the deep end!)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `order_by`, `desc` or `asc` in Mongoid, it's passing it to MongoDB to be sorted on the database server and it's looking for a field named `countries_ive_drunk_count`, which doesn't exist. You would need to store the data in MongoDB for it to be able to sort everything.

You haven't listed much of your schema, but you should look at using a group query to figure out the top drinkers.